# Colorbox in fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, theorems

I was thinking if the marks (with `extramarks`) done in theorem-defined environments could be adapted to the different styles I created (theorem, definition, remark).
My idea would be to make appear theorems, corollaries, prepositions [···] in dark-gray color box; definitions [···] in gray and finally, remarks in light-gray. In fact, if you look at the code, that is what I managed to do with \newtheoremstyles. For now, they are all in a dark-gray color (defined as “arsenic”), except for remarks which are in light-gray. My question would be how would I have to modify the code if I want the `\theoremmarks` header text to appear in the particular color the theorem environment is defined as.

---

### Note

[image]
*For everyone who hasn't yet understood what I want to do*: As you can see, theorem-defined environments' labels are in colorboxes. Every environment has a color of its own associated. I want to know if there's any way to put the circled number (top right corner, odd pages) in a colorbox of the linked color.

---

## MRE

#### `styles.sty`

```
\ProvidesPackage{styles}

% Packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[catalan]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{emptypage}

% Parameters
\geometry{a4paper, total={170mm,257mm}, left=19.1mm, right=19.1mm, top=25.4mm, bottom=25.4mm}

% Header
\usepackage{extramarks}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\definecolor{arsenic}{rgb}{0.23, 0.27, 0.29}
\definecolor{lightsilver}{RGB}{248, 248, 248}
\definecolor{silver}{RGB}{245, 245, 245}
\definecolor{darksilver}{RGB}{230, 230, 230}
\definecolor{ultralight}{RGB}{253, 253, 253}

% Save standard definitions
\let\HeadRule\headrule
% Add color to standard definitions.
\renewcommand\headrule{\color{lightgray}\HeadRule}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}


\fancypagestyle{nor}{% <===========================================
    \fancyhead[RE]{\textcolor{black}{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\textcolor{black}{\nouppercase{\lastrightxmark}}}
    \fancyhead[CE,CO]{}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\textbf{\textcolor{arsenic}{{\botmarks\theoremmarks}}}}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\textcolor{black}{\textit{\lastleftxmark}}}
    \fancyfoot[RO, LE]{\fontsize{10pt}{10pt}\selectfont\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[CO, CE]{}
    \fancyheadoffset[LE,RO]{+0.025\textwidth}
    \fancyheadoffset[RE,LO]{+0.0\textwidth}
}
\fancypagestyle{toc}{% <===========================================
    \fancyhead[RE,LO,RO,LE]{}
    \fancyhead[CE,CO]{\textsc{Índex}}
    \fancyfoot[RO, LE]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[CO, CE]{}
    \fancyheadoffset[]{+0.025\textwidth}
}
\fancypagestyle{toenv}{% <===========================================
    \fancyhead[RE,LO,RO,LE]{}
    \fancyhead[CE,CO]{\textsc{Taula}}
    \fancyfoot[RO, LE]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[CO, CE]{}
    \fancyheadoffset[]{+0.025\textwidth}
}
\fancypagestyle{intr}{% <===========================================
    \fancyhead[RE,LO,RO,LE]{}
    \fancyhead[CE,CO]{\textsc{Introducció}}
    \fancyfoot[RO, LE]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[CO, CE]{}
    \fancyheadoffset[]{+0.025\textwidth}
}
% Pieter Van Oostrum - "In fancyhdr version 3, the initialisation was done when the first \pagestyle{fancy} (or one of its derived pagestyles) was given, including the initialisation of \chaptermark and \sectionmark"
\pagestyle{nor}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}\extramarks{}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\extramarks{\thesection}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\extramarks{\thesubsection}{#1}}

\newmarks\theoremmarks
\apptocmd\@begintheorem
   {\message{\@currenvir: #2}\marks\theoremmarks{#2}}
   {\message{patch \string\@begintheorem}}{\FAIL\@begintheorem}



% Definicions, teoremes, lemes...

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{theorem}%
{}{}{\itshape}{-.325em}{\bfseries}{}{.5em} 
{
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{1pt}\colorbox{darksilver}{\color{arsenic}\thmname{#1}%
    \thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }\@upn{#2}}%
    \thmnote{ {(\textsc{\the\thm@notefont#3})}}.}%
}
\makeatother


\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}[theorem]{Proposició}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lema}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corol·lari}
\newtheorem{property}[theorem]{Propietat}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjectura}
\newtheorem{process}[theorem]{Procés}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercici}[section]

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{definition}%
{}{}{}{-.325em}{\bfseries}{}{.5em} 
{
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{1pt}\colorbox{silver}{\color{arsenic}\thmname{#1}%
    \thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }\@upn{#2}}%
    \thmnote{ {(\textsc{\the\thm@notefont#3})}}.}%
}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definició}
\newtheorem{exmp}[theorem]{Exemple}
\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notació}

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{remark}%
{}{}{}{-.325em}{\bfseries}{}{.5em} 
{
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{1pt}\colorbox{lightsilver}{\color{arsenic}\thmname{#1}%
    \thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }\@upn{#2}}%
    \thmnote{ {(\textsc{\the\thm@notefont#3})}}.}%
}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Observació}

% Renew commands, canvis de format
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\color{gray}$\blacksquare$}

% TITLE FORMAT
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{array}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\itshape\Large\centering\color{black}}{\centering\Huge\bfseries\sc\romannumeral\thechapter}{1ex}{\titleline{\color{lightgray}\titlerule[0.1pt]\vspace{1ex}}#1}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]{\itshape\Large\centering\color{black}}{}{1ex}{#1}[\titleline{\color{lightgray}\titlerule[0.1pt]\vspace{1ex}}]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{40pt}
\titleformat{\section}[frame]
{\color{lightgray}\large\normalfont\mdseries\scshape\centering}{\filcenter\small \quad\textcolor{black}{\textit{\thesection}}\quad}
{1ex}{\color{black}\Large\bfseries\filcenter#1}[]
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\normalfont\mdseries\scshape\centering}{\color{lightgray}\textit{\thesubsection}}{2ex}{\colorbox{ultralight}{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.1pt\hspace{2ex}}p{0.85\textwidth}}\raggedright#1\end{tabular}}}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
```

#### `main.tex`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{styles}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section A}
\kant[1]
\begin{remark}
Note that remark ("observació") labels are in a light gray box, whereas in a theorem environment they are dark gray colored.
\end{remark}
\begin{definition}
Definitions ("definició") are of a different gray, too.
\end{definition}
\begin{theorem}\label{th}
Test theorem. On the odd pages, code is programmed to display the number of the last math-defined environment in the page. So, I would want \verb|\theoremmarks| header text to appear in the particular color the theorem environment is defined as.
\end{theorem}
\kant[2-7]
\subsection{LOOK AT THE TOP RIGHT CORNER!}
We have to modify code in order to achieve what I mentioned in \ref{th}.
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please supply a compileable small example, with a dummy test theorem. With many multiple guesses, I cannot reproduce your scenario. Everything runs OK. Perhaps: Do you mean you want to put `\colorbox{darksilver}{\color{arsenic}...}` in the header just like in the theorems? Or do you want to put theorem type-specific formatting `\colorbox{\thtypecolorbg}{\color{\thtypecolorfg}...}`? Unrelated: is the `apptocmd` patch, with all its `@`s, *outside* the `makeat...` environment?

Comment: Hey! Thanks for replying. I edited the post and I attached a MRE, as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an extense response from @Cicada and some research, I solved it (some time ago) using `extramarks`, which I already used to keep track of my theorem-defined environments.

```
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{theorem}{}{}{\itshape}{}{\bfseries}{}{.5em}%
{%
\xdef\boxcolor{darksilver}%
\xdef\fontcolor{arsenic}%
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\colorbox{\boxcolor}{\color{\fontcolor}\thmname{#1}%
\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }\@upn{#2}}%
\thmnote{ {(\textsc{\the\thm@notefont#3})}}.}%
}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%% MORE CODE... %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Color de la capsa
\makeatletter
\newmarks\colorboxmark
\apptocmd\@begintheorem
{\message{\@currenvir: #2}\marks\colorboxmark{\boxcolor}}
{\message{patch \string\@begintheorem}}{\FAIL\@begintheorem}
\makeatother
% Color de la lletra
\makeatletter
\newmarks\colorthmmark
\apptocmd\@begintheorem
{\message{\@currenvir: #2}\marks\colorthmmark{\fontcolor}}
{\message{patch \string\@begintheorem}}{\FAIL\@begintheorem}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%% MORE CODE... %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\fancyhead[RO]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\colorbox{\botmarks\colorboxmark}{\color{\botmarks\colorthmmark}\textbf{\botmarks\theoremmarks}}}
```

I have been as brief as possible, as this thread has not received the interest I believed it would. If anyone wants more details, please don't hesitate to reach out.

Answer (score 1):

*Amended answer*

(1) Define a new command to hold a colour name, `\newcommand\thhdrcolor{Fuchsia}`, say.

(2) Globally redefine it inside each theoremstyle definition. The key part is that the reset needs to be seen outside the th/def/remark environments, so has to be global, not local  (I used `\xdef`).

I used red, green, blue, just to exaggerate: `\xdef\thhdrcolor{red}` for theorem:

```
\newtheoremstyle{theorem}%
{}{}{\itshape}{-.325em}{\bfseries}{}{.5em} 
{
\xdef\thhdrcolor{red}%******************
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{1pt}\colorbox{darksilver}{\color{\thhdrcolor}\thmname{#1}%
    \thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }\@upn{#2}}%
    \thmnote{ {(\textsc{\the\thm@notefont#3})}}.}%
}
```

Similarly for the other two.

[image: all three]

(3) Put the colourname command in the header definition:

```
    \fancyhead[RO]{\textbf{\textcolor{\thhdrcolor}{x{\botmarks\theoremmarks}x}}}%******************
```

Result:

Adding enough pages with enough remarks and definitions gives:

[image: red]

[image: green]

[image: blue]

The `x` is just my marking.

---

*Original answer*

I edited the definition of `arsenic` to `\definecolor{arsenic}{RGB}{250, 120, 0}`, to more clearly see what is going on.

If I understand your question correctly,the code is already working.

The colour is coming through into the header:

[image: top right corner]

and is also in the theorem:

[image: theorem colour]

So, with that as a basis, if I have misunderstood, what is your requirement?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. ```arsenic``` is hardcoded into the header with this line: ```\fancyhead[RO]{\textbf{\textcolor{arsenic}{{\botmarks\theoremmarks}}}}```. What I would want is some sort of modification on this line to automatically change the font color depending on if the number is a theorem, a definition or a remark, respectively. It would be something like, as you commented, ```\colorbox{\thtypecolorbg}{\color{\thtypecolorfg}...}```.

Comment: @mariovilar Do you want theorem/definition/remark to set, say, `\thhdrcolor`, with `\thhdrcolor` being used in the header definition: `\fancyhead[RO]{\textbf{\textcolor{\thhdrcolor}{{\botmarks\theoremmarks}}}}`?

Comment: NICE! Solved. I was planning to do so with colorboxes, but your approach with textcolor seems even more elegant. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hey! After some time playing with the code, it's great but not complete: it seems to have a little trouble with page breaks (the theorem number is correct but it takes the color of the theorem on the next page, which might be different).

Comment: Ask a separate question, so more eyes are on it. Link back to this question. Users/readers won't be expecting to go through the comments for additional questions.